# How to find the presentation time stamp of a given frame number for FFMPEG decoding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am using the C APIs of ffmpeg for some video processing. My aim is to extract the screen shot of a given frame number. I have understood that ffmpeg has an av_seek_frame function to seek to a given timestamp(expressed in appropriated base units of the video stream). I assume that I will have to goto to the most recent I frame for the given frame(using the AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD flag) and read onwards untill I meet the required frame. For that I need to give a seek time stamp to the av_seek_frame function. My main issue is that given a frame number, how do I find an associated presentation time stamp to seek to ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea, in my experience `pkt.pts` increased by `pkt.duration` times per frame and it's constant if frame rate is constant.

Check `pkt.duration` and `pkt.pts` increase per frame. If you confirm increase is constant. Rest is easy to compute pts/frame number by dividing or multiplying by `duration`.

Hope that helps.